# What is exact use of clientglobalcontext.js.aspx in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011

In sample example in SDK and at different places on internet `Clientglobalcontext.js.aspx` file is mentioned, if I do not include it in my html web resource, it throws exception, but if I include file like,

```
<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then only rest endpoint API is working. Now, I am not able to locate this file anywhere. What is exact use of this file? How to locate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` is to provide the `GetGlobalContext` function.

It's all explained inside MSDN:

[GetGlobalContext function and ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx (client-side reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328541.aspx#BKMK_GetGlobalContext)

> The GetGlobalContext function returns the same context object found in
>   the Xrm.Page.context.

The file is generated server-side, practically the `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` push a JavaScript file to the client when it is included with the `<script>` tag syntax.

Comment: This is not working in CRM 2016 online instance. Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: it works on CRM 2016 Online, I just used it few days ago

Comment: Can you please help me how it works in html which is opened in separately new window. Please answer at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502033/xrm-context-in-html-webreource-in-mscrm-2016?noredirect=1#comment64430112_38502033