# XRM context in HTML webreource in MSCRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am facing a problem when HTML web resource which gets popped up on clicking of some ribbon button.

It does not have the Xrm context as it is unable to load the file **clientglobalcontext.js.aspx**

Here is what I have included in source of HTML:
 **src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"**
and also used this
**src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"**

This is working in my current CRM11 version but it does not get load in CRM16 online. Is there any other way to load this file in a popped up html window or it is not possible to access the XRM context from separate HTML file in CRM 2016 ?

Much Thank You.

Comment: Please include the code included in your HTML web resource that loads `clientglobalcontext.js.aspx` and also please show the relative path of your html resource

Comment: The same code which is mentioned below in my HTML

Comment: The code in the other question? The poster there put 3 different approaches. It's not clear what you have used. Please update your question with more detail

Comment: Updated the question. Please let me know if more info required.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you need to consider

1. Using a relative path including the root WebResources folder, for example, /WebResources/ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx, is not recommended because it can cause the page to lose organization context in a multi-tenant environment.

2.If you have Web resource name as "new_sample.html" then we need to refer as below

```js
 <script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></script>
```

3. If you have Web resource name as "new_/sample.html" then we need to refer as below

```js
<script src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></script>
```

4. If you have Web resource name as "new_/content/sample.html" then we need to refer as below

```js
<script src="../../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></script>
```

Comment: I did not get your point regarding the question, I said I implemented the code as you have mentioned but it is not working in CRM online 2016. Is there any other way to load the file 'clientglobalcontext.js.aspx' in popped up html window ?